# Python: Add mixin per decorator with static type checker support

Tags: python, mixins, typing

TL;DR: How to add a Mixin to a class with a decorator in a way that is understandable for static type checkers in VSCode?

Its possible to dynamically add a Mixin to an existing class with a decorator:

```py
class Mixin:
    b: int

def add_mixin(cls):
    return type(cls.__name__, (cls, Mixin), {})

@add_mixin
class A:
    a: int

a = A()  # a has type Any
a.a      # a.a has type Any
a.b      # a.b has type Any
```

With this setup, the static type checker in VSCode assigns `Any` to all variables. I want to modify this decorator such that the type checker can correctly identify the types for both `a.a` and `a.b`. Desired result:

```py
class Mixin:
    b: int

T = TypeVar("T")

def add_mixin(cls: Type[T]) -> "??":
    return type(cls.__name__, (cls, Mixin), {})

@add_mixin
class A:
    a: int

a = A()  # a has type A
a.a      # a.a has type int
a.b      # a.b has type int
```

I tried adding type annotations in various ways, but no variant has lead to the desired result. Either the type for `a.a` or for `a.b` is correctly identified but not both. The `Intersection` (https://github.com/python/typing/issues/213) type sounds exactly like what I am looking for, but its not there yet. Is there some workaround to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: yeah I don't think you are going to be able to do this without support for intersection types. The PEP is still being worked on, it hasn't even been submitted, but I know a lot of people want this.